# Wordpress Jquery Confliction with Plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, conflict

I am building a Wordpress website for a client and it is going to have an e-store. I'm using wp-ecommerce. All of the store pages are loading with a javascript error:

http://www.thecollectiveclothingco.com/products-page/t-shirts/

```
jQuery("form.product_form").livequery is not a function
[Break On This Error] jQuery("form.product_form").livequery(function(){
```

After some extensive google-age, I believe I've diagnosed the issue as a script conflict. In other words, either WP or the plugin itself is serving up jquery, and I'm also including it for some other things on the site. When I delete my jquery script call, the issue goes away and the store works fine. But I need that jquery...

I've read about using WP enqeue to fix the issue:

```
function my_init_method() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    }
}    
add_action('init', 'my_init_method');php wp_head();
```

I believe I've done this right, but does not seem to be fixing anything.

Any ideas? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to execute your jquery with a noConflict option
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

eg,

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
// Do something with jQuery
j("div p").hide();
// Do something with another library's $()
$("content").style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: Michal,

Thank you for your quick response. I gave this a shot and it I'm still receiving the same error. :(

Comment: I looked at your site - it seems that the problem is with the ecommerce plugin you are using. The library relies on the plugin called livequery which since has become part of the main jQuery release - in jquery 1.4.4 which you are using .live method has the same functionality as livequery - or  try including livequery plugin - or update your e-commerce plugin to the latest version. Last resort simply search and replace all .livequery with .live in your plugin source - the other syntax is the same so you might be ok.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I figured it out... it was the enqueue script that fixed things. I wp(head); had to come before the deregister and enqueue part. I must have read the documentation wrong. Here's what I added to my header:

```
<?php
wp_head();
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery', MYURL .'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js', FALSE, '1.4.4');
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked for an answer on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/?