# Jquery conflict in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, conflict

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wordpress Jquery Confliction with Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845483/wordpress-jquery-confliction-with-plugin)

I have a conflict, I know what is causing it, but after lengthy research, not sure how to solve it.  My site uses a coda slider for the slider, BUT when I use a plugin WPreviews it causes the slider to stop...

SO, it is clear that after research it is the infamous $ jquery conflicting with the plugin, but interesting enough on my other site I use the same plugin without issues.

ANY assistance would be greatly appreciated and a FREE Decals to those who help me solve it.

Thank you very much for your consideration and help.

Comment: Wrap whatever makes jQuery calls in `(function($){ //code })(jQuery);. I mean everything, `$(document).ready(function(){});` and all.

Comment: site was broken (php erors) when I looked but it is really common issue in wordpress where jQuery plugins keep adding jQuery library for eac plugin. This over writes the jQuery object and any plugins previously attached are wiped out. Make sure jQuery only loading once and before all plugins