# Wordpress JS conflict (?) - PrettyPhoto, jQuery

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto

I've been going berserk all afternoon trying to solve this issue, but I guess I just don't know enough Javascript to see what to do. Read through lots and lots of posts, including here, but I still can't figure out what to do.

I'm currently using a Wordpress theme that I bought from a designer, who since then has disappeared and doesn't reply any message regarding the theme.

On this theme, I've been using for more than a year the simple and elegant "PrettyPhoto" lightbox plugin (http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/).

Everything used to work just fine, but today I suddenly discovered that the "lightbox" effect is now cancelled: every photo now opens underneath the main page, instead of popping up in a floating window -- and it looks really, really ugly (see example here).

From what I understand it's probably a kind of javascript conflict happening within my theme, but I can't put my finger on it. I had a jQuery 1.8.2 file in my JS directory, but replacing it with version 1.9.1 brought no joy.

Firebug gives me the following JS error:

```
    TypeError: $ is not a function      $('#navigation ul.menu').supersubs({          -   seso.js (line 2)
Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'
TypeError: $ is not a function      $('#navigation ul.menu').supersubs({              - seso.js (line 2)
```

'Seso.js' is a file that comes with my theme (named "Seso"), and of which the code is as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#navigation ul.menu').supersubs({ 
            minWidth:    15,
            maxWidth:    30,
            extraWidth:  1     
        }).superfish({ hoverClass: "sfHover", speed: 'slow', dropShadows: false, delay: 0, animation: {height:'show'}});
    $('.up a[href$="top"]').click( function() {
        $.scrollTo( $('#top'), {speed:1200} );
    })
    $('#navigation ul.menu>li>ul>li, #navigation ul.menu>li>ul>li>ul>li').hover(function() { //mouse in
        $(this).stop().animate({ paddingLeft: '5px' }, 300);
    }, function() { //mouse out
    $(this).stop().animate({ paddingLeft: 0 }, 300);
    });
    $(".socialtip").tipTip();
    jQuery(".toggle_body").hide(); 

    jQuery("h4.toggle").toggle(function(){
        jQuery(this).addClass("toggle_active");
        }, function () {
        jQuery(this).removeClass("toggle_active");
    });

    jQuery("h4.toggle").click(function(){
        jQuery(this).next(".toggle_body").slideToggle();

    });
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({animationSpeed:'slow',theme:'facebook',slideshow:5000});
    var enable_image_hover = function(image){
        if(image.is(".portfolio")){
            if (jQuery.browser.msie && parseInt(jQuery.browser.version, 10) < 7) {} else {
                if (jQuery.browser.msie && parseInt(jQuery.browser.version, 10) < 9) {
                    image.hover(function(){
                        jQuery(".image_overlay",this).css("visibility", "visible");
                    },function(){
                        jQuery(".image_overlay",this).css("visibility", "hidden");
                    }).children('img').after('<span class="image_overlay"></span>');
                }else{
                    image.hover(function(){
                        jQuery(".image_overlay",this).animate({
                            opacity: '1'
                        },"fast");
                    },function(){
                        jQuery(".image_overlay",this).animate({
                            opacity: '0'
                        },"fast");
                    }).children('img').after(jQuery('<span class="image_overlay"></span>').css({opacity: '0',visibility:'visible'}));
                }
            }
        }       
    }

    $('.portfolio').preloader({
        delay:200,
        imgSelector:'.imgbg img',
        beforeShow:function(){
            $(this).closest('.image_frame').addClass('preloading');
        },
        afterShow:function(){
            var image = jQuery(this).closest('.image_frame').removeClass('preloading').children("a");
            enable_image_hover(image);
        }
    });
    $('.post').preloader({
        delay:100,
        imgSelector:'.postimage img',
        beforeShow:function(){
            $(this).closest('.postimage').addClass('preloading');
        },
        afterShow:function(){
            var image = jQuery(this).closest('.postimage').removeClass('preloading');
        }
    });
});
(function($) {

    $.fn.preloader = function(options) {
        var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.preloader.defaults, options);


        return this.each(function() {
            settings.beforeShowAll.call(this);
            var imageHolder = $(this);

            var images = imageHolder.find(settings.imgSelector).css({opacity:0, visibility:'hidden'});  
            var count = images.length;
            var showImage = function(image,imageHolder){
                if(image.data.source != undefined){
                    imageHolder = image.data.holder;
                    image = image.data.source;  
                };

                count --;
                if(settings.delay <= 0){
                    image.css('visibility','visible').animate({opacity:1}, settings.animSpeed, function(){settings.afterShow.call(this)});
                }
                if(count == 0){
                    imageHolder.removeData('count');
                    if(settings.delay <= 0){
                        settings.afterShowAll.call(this);
                    }else{
                        if(settings.gradualDelay){
                            images.each(function(i,e){
                                var image = $(this);
                                setTimeout(function(){
                                    image.css('visibility','visible').animate({opacity:1}, settings.animSpeed, function(){settings.afterShow.call(this)});
                                },settings.delay*(i+1));
                            });
                            setTimeout(function(){settings.afterShowAll.call(imageHolder[0])}, settings.delay*images.length+settings.animSpeed);
                        }else{
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                images.each(function(i,e){
                                    $(this).css('visibility','visible').animate({opacity:1}, settings.animSpeed, function(){settings.afterShow.call(this)});
                                });
                                setTimeout(function(){settings.afterShowAll.call(imageHolder[0])}, settings.animSpeed);
                            }, settings.delay);
                        }
                    }
                }
            };


            images.each(function(i){
                settings.beforeShow.call(this);

                image = $(this);

                if(this.complete==true){
                    showImage(image,imageHolder);
                }else{
                    image.bind('error load',{source:image,holder:imageHolder}, showImage);
                    if($.browser.opera){
                        image.trigger("load");//for hidden image
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    };


    //Default settings
    $.fn.preloader.defaults = {
        delay:1000,
        gradualDelay:true,
        imgSelector:'img',
        animSpeed:500,
        beforeShowAll: function(){},
        beforeShow: function(){},
        afterShow: function(){},
        afterShowAll: function(){}
    };
})(jQuery);
```

I didn't build this JS file, so I don't know exactly what all of its functions are for. I'm quite sure I don't need 90% of them.

For the sake of completeness, here are the contents of my current WP header.php head tag:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type') ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset') ?>" />
<title><?php if (is_front_page()) { ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> - <?php bloginfo('description'); ?><?php } else { ?><?php wp_title($sep = ''); ?> - <?php bloginfo('name'); ?><?php } ?></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $themePath ?>/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $themePath ?>/css/imageflow.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $themePath ?>/css/options.php" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<?php if(get_option_tree ('customcss', '')){ ?>
<style type="text/css">
<?php echo  get_option_tree ('customcss', ''); ?>
</style>
<?php } ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">   
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $("a[href$='.jpg'], a[href$='.jpeg'], a[href$='.gif'], a[href$='.png']").prettyPhoto({
    animationSpeed: 'normal', /* fast/slow/normal */
    padding: 40, /* padding for each side of the picture */
    opacity: 0.35, /* Value betwee 0 and 1 */
    showTitle: true, /* true/false */
    theme: 'pp_default' /* light_rounded / dark_rounded / light_square / dark_square / facebook */      
    }); 

})

</script>
</head>
```

I've tried using other lightbox plugins, but the result is the same.

The strangest thing is that PrettyPhoto does work on my local server -- the main difference between the local and online versions of my site being that the latter is a newer version of Wordpress...

There is some deep JS conflict inside my theme, but I can't find its source. If anyone has a clue, all help would be strongly appreciated!

Cheers,
D-

Comment: Why is that file mixing use of `$()` and `jQuery()`? Pick one and go with it, sounds like the issues is being caused by something else taking over the `$` character.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wordpress Jquery Confliction with Plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845483/wordpress-jquery-confliction-with-plugin)

Comment: You can try `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {$("doAnything");});`. This is also described in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Answer (score 0):

The JavaSript error is telling you exactly what the problem is - `TypeError: $ is not a function` , so the script is failing.

In WordPress, you need to use `jQuery` and not `$`, so for your code replace

```
$('#navigation ul.menu')
```

with

```
jQuery('#navigation ul.menu')
```

and similarly replace in the other function calls where `$` is used.

Why is this? jQuery defines the `$` function normally but to prevent conflict with other libraries using `$`, it can be run in [`.noconflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode.

From [another plugin's](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers) documentation

> The jQuery library included with WordPress is set to the noConflict() mode (see wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js). This is to prevent compatibility problems with other JavaScript libraries that WordPress can link

Also see answer on [**wordpress.stackexchange.com**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91594/wordpress-and-jquery/91598#91598).