# The Conflict of jQuery on WP (Admin Panel doesn't work correctly)

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm using a custom Wordpress Theme for my blog. This theme is working good in the website but on the back, the widgets can't moving/automatically closing etc. I've tried to solve this problem with

`define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );`

on WP-config. It solved the problem for widgets but right now, I can't upload featured image for posts. (It shows me an error about it couldn't upload, but it uploads and I can't see the library in wp-admin/post.php. I can see all images in wp-admin/upload.php

My functions.php looks like that:

```
function aax_scripts() {
// Styles
wp_enqueue_style( 'Bootstrap-4', get_template_directory_uri().'/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'AAX-Style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
wp_enqueue_style( 'Google-Fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|Roboto|Libre+Franklin');
wp_enqueue_style( 'Font-Awesome', get_template_directory_uri().'/fontawesome/fontawesome-free-5.2.0-web/css/all.css');

// Scripts

wp_enqueue_script("jquery");
wp_enqueue_script( 'Bootstrap-4', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script( 'Popper', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/popper.min.js');
};
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'aax_scripts' );
```

What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you loading two versions of jQuery?  What happens if you remove the wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); function?  You can also first deregister jquery, before you enqueue it, to make sure there is only one: wp_deregister_script('jquery');

Comment: No, I checked before. Actually I was using custom jquery. I changed WP's jquery and then I noticed the widget problem solved. But I can't see anything in media library except Media tab (upload.php) zone.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42420249/wordpress-4-7-2-library-doesnt-load-the-media the problem looks same.

Comment: Any error messages in the browser's console?  If so, please add to post.  Also, if you have any in your php_error.log, please share those that apply.

Comment: Browser Console: 

It seems that this site is using the scroll-linked positioning effect. This effect may not work properly with asynchronous panning. For details, see https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Performance/ScrollLinkedEffects, and you can participate in discussion of related tools and features.

There is no PHP errrors. I just see loading gif when I try upload "Featured image" on post edit tab.

Comment: The main problem is that, **Featured Image** tab is not working. It's not showing my media library and their thumbnails, it can't upload a new image. (Actually it uploads to Library but shows an error about it couldn't.) Just loading icon.

Comment: Did you disable all the plugins and then re-enable them one at a time, testing the featured image tab each time?  Also, switch to a different generic theme and test again to see if it's your theme.  That will at least give you a place to start looking.

Comment: Yes, there is no problem with generic themes.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/featured-images-not-appearing-6/  Is this the same error you're receiving?  Try installing the Health Check plugin they mention in this exchange.

Comment: The problem is similar but not the same. There is a problem about my theme which affects my admin page. The problem had been solved when I changed my theme. I can't really understand what is the connection between admin theme and my theme?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress Jquery Confliction with Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845483/wordpress-jquery-confliction-with-plugin)

Comment: you would have to add `wp_deregister_script('jquery');` before registering it (once again).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. This problem is not about jQuery.

The source of problem is a commenting function in theme's function.php file.

```
if ( $GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages < 2 ) {
```

The function includes a global query and WP using queries everywhere. It was looking cool on page but it doesn't means it's a good code.

Be careful your functions. Don't be me.